# The problem of converting very large numbers to infinity in Python

Tags: python

I want to calculate larg numbers and draw a diagram of these at the end, but it gives infinity for one of the data
what should i do to it gives me number ?

```
from decimal import Decimal 
q=10**23
N=10**10
x=0
while True:
    try:
        a=Decimal(((q+N)/q)**q)/1
        break
    except OverflowError:
        x+=1
        q=q/10
num=str(a).split("E+")
num[0]=float(num[0])
num[1]=int(num[1])
for i in range(0,x):
    num[0]=num[0]*num[0]
    num[1]=num[1]+num[1]
j=str(num[0])+"e+"+str(num[1])
j=Decimal(float(str(num[0])+"e+"+str(num[1])))
print(j)
```

j is 1.0428350774673307e+377487360
but it is gives Infinity

Comment: Don't use that intermediate cast to float.

Comment: What are you doing with such large numbers?

Comment: Hi, was your question answered? If so, could you please accept and upvote the answer? If not, what can be clarified?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
j=Decimal(float(str(num[0])+"e+"+str(num[1])))
```

to this:

```
j=Decimal(str(num[0])+"e+"+str(num[1]))
```

When you cast a gigantic number to a float, it's outside the set of values that can be represented. Gigantic numbers then become infinity. This approach will work instead, because you doing go through that intermediate bottleneck.

```
print(j)
# Decimal('1.0428350774673307E+377487360')
```

But also—think about why you're doing this. You almost never need a number that large. There's probably a better way.